# Qt: force resource reloading on every compilation

Tags: qt, qt4

Is there a way to force QtCreator to recompile all the resources (images / qss files) i have specified in my qrc file every time i build the project?

Currently if i change some styles in my qss file but dont remove the file and re-add it to the qrc file the old version of my qss file is used.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34954400/1223728

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is an easy way to automatically cause the qrc file to rebuild.  However, you should be able to add a dependency on the individual files to the qrc file target using `qmake` somehow.  I have to admit I'm not sure how to do it, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
RCC_DIR = ../myproject/resources
```

in your project file (`*.PRO`)